# Content in meta tag

Tags: asp.net-core, browser, character-encoding, meta-tags

Like the first image, the meta tag is displayed correctly in inspect elements mode but incorrectly displayed in view page source mode as in the second image. Thank you for suggesting a solution to this problem.
[image: First image]

[image: second image]

Comment: Does it lead to some error on your html view?

Comment: According to Google documents, for the SEO site, the text in the meta tag must be the same as the original language of the site. The text content of my site's url meta tag is displayed correctly in the inspect element, but is displayed in the view page source as a hash! In the meantime, I call the content of the tag from the database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and according to what you said, I'm afraid the display issue may come from the browser encoding. Did you try to open your website in another browser? Per my searching, we need to install extensions in chrome to solve the issue. Could you pls take a try?

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem is present in all browsers

Comment: Hmmm, did you try to change the encoding to utf-8 in those browsers?

Comment: I used utf8 immediately after starting the head tag.

Comment: I used the following tag for utf8:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Yeah I saw it in your screenshot, I mean that the display issue doesn't come from your js code but may come from the browser encoding setting.

Comment: I mean , for example you can add `Set Character Encoding` in chrome and right click to change encoding type on the source code page to see it worked. And, when you view source code, except the content of mata tag, if there's other content displayed error? Or just in meta tag?

Comment: Per my searching, when the website showed well but issue in source code page, it more likely to be the issue from the browser.

Comment: The Persian text is correct on the whole screen, but as soon as it is used in the meta tag, it has this problem

Comment: *"the text in the meta tag must be the same as the original language of the site..."* Are you sure that you have a problem here? If an seo bot reads the text as written or as encoded, is it not reading the original language? I'm not sure, but I would look around to see if this is actually a problem.

Comment: I understood the answer :

Answer (score 0):

I understood the answer:

Because, by default, the HTML encoding engine will only safelist the basic latin alphabet (because browsers have bugs. So we're trying to protect against unknown problems). The &XXX values you see still render as correctly as you can see in your screen shots, so there's no real harm, aside from the increased page size.

If the increased page size bothers you then you can customise the encoder to safe list your own character pages (not language, Unicode doesn't think in terms on language)

To widen the characters treated as safe by the encoder you would insert the following line into the ConfigureServices() method in startup.cs;

```
    services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(
  HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
                                            UnicodeRanges.Arabic }));
```

Arabic has quite a few blocks in Unicode, so you may need to add more blocks to get the full range you need.